# In Latex why does changing the color of an integral domain changes the spacing

Tags: math, latex, integral

Why does changing the color of an integral domain changes the spacing?
As you can see the upper bound x in this integral has been shifted right.

[image]
$\int_{\color{red}-\infty}^{x}pdf(x)dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\mathcolor` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

$\int_{\mathcolor{red}{-\infty}}^{x}pdf(x)dx$

\end{document}
```